# Axios response.data is string of the XML data instead of JSON object

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, rest, xml, json

Axios get call receiving the right information but it comes back as a string of the XML data. I need a JSON object.

I am grabbing all the tables on the page then I filter through them and then I want to make a REST call that will only give me the Choice fields. The variable current list name gets the guid and that is later concat'd for the url.

```
        var currentListName = table.getAttribute("id").substring(1, 37);
        var root = ctx.HttpRoot;
        var listName = "SP.Data." + table.summary + "ListItem";
        var data = {
          __metadata: { type: listName },
        };
        var url =
          root +
          "/_api/web/lists('" +
          currentListName +
          `')/fields?$filter=TypeDisplayName eq 'Choice'`;
        var configureAxios = {
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            credentials: true,
            "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value,
          },
        };
        axios
          .get(url, { data: JSON.stringify(data) }, configureAxios)
          .then(function (res) {
            console.log("response:", res);
        })
          .catch(function (e) {
            console.log("error:", e);
          });
        });
```

I get the response.data being a string of the XML data. I want to be JSON so I can access the values within. I'm possibly missing something in the headers?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out that I was sending data in my GET request! Huge mistake. I copied over for a different rest call I was making possibly a POST and it has the data piece.

```
 axios.get(url, configureAxios).then(function (res){}
```

Answer (score 0):

My test code for your reference:

```
 axios.get(`${_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl}/_api/lists/getbytitle('test')/fields?$filter=TypeDisplayName eq 'Choice'`)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Test Result:
[image]

Comment: What did did you put for your headers?

Comment: I did not put the header parameter.